# How to search for a multiple column in "where" clause which may be null sometimes but others should work if they aren't null

Tags: php, mysql, json, html

I want to write a single query instead of "if" statements which should be able to fetch filter applied data

The columns passed in "where" clause are:

```
usedBy,item_type,item_rarity,item_slot

filters={"hero":"Axe","type":"Weapon","rarity":"rare","slot":"hand","title":"Blood Shed"}
```

In above json all filters are applied and no null value so the simple sql query works great,for example

```
Select * from table where usedBy = 'Axe' and item_type = 'weapon' and item_rarity='rare' and item_slot = 'hand' and item_title = 'Blood shed'
```

But if anyone of them is null i wont get any result.
for example :

```
filters={"hero":"Axe","type":"","rarity":"","slot":"","title":""}
```

So I want a query which can handle both the above requests at the same time.

Tried queries are(variables are used):

```
SELECT usedBy,item_type,item_name,item_slot,item_rarity from descriptions where usedBy = '$hero' and item_type ='$type' or item_type = '' and item_rarity='$rarity' or item_rarity ='' and item_slot='$slot' or item_slot = '' and item_name = '$title' or item_name=''
```

result for above query:

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X6Cu.png)

```
SELECT usedBy,item_type,item_name,item_slot,item_rarity from descriptions where usedBy = '$hero' and item_type ='$type' or item_type != '' and item_rarity='$rarity' or item_rarity !='' and item_slot='$slot' or item_slot != '' and item_name = '$title' or item_name !=''
```

Above query shown all the records of the table

[Result :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5auk.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try use of % sign with Like
For example:

SELECT usedBy,item_type,item_name,item_slot,item_rarity from descriptions where usedBy LIke '%$hero%' and item_type LIKE '%$type%' ;

Comment: This is a nice idea, but might not always work. What if there are _rarity_ values 'rare' and 'rarer'? Then both will be hit with `item_rarity = '%rare%'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but sadly it didn't work for me,i got null result if anyone of them us null

Comment: @MohammadShaheryar That should not happen. Please be specific in what you write: `null` is not the same as an empty string `''`. Have you grouped the conditions correctly? like: `WHERE (... OR ...) AND (... OR ...) AND (... OR ...)`?

Comment: ops my bad,that is an empty string not null and yes i have tried it with different ways too.Should i apply if conditions on them ?

Answer (score 0):

You must build your WHERE condition dynamically and put only variable that are not empty :

```
// build a list of conditions based on filters data
$conditions= array();
if($filters['hero'] != '')
    $conditions[] = "usedBy = '" . $filters['hero'] . "'" ;
if($filters['type'] != '')
    $conditions[] = "type = '" . $filters['type'] . "'" ;
....

// build the SQL query
$query = "SELECT usedBy,item_type,item_name,item_slot,item_rarity from descriptions where " . implode(' AND ', $conditions)
```

In this situation, make sure you validate and escape correctly your data to avoid SQL injections.